# Why do ionic compounds form in the exact ratios that they do instead of more variable ratios?

Tags: bond, ionic-compounds

I read that e.g. $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ come together because of electrostatic force or coulomb force and form an ionic bond. Then why is the formula $\ce{MgCl2}$? Why does one $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ attract only two chlorides (if Coulomb's law is at work) and form an ionic bond with two chlorides only? When the ions come close and form a bond, they don't distribute the charge i.e. their electrons in such a way that they would have the same potential. They remain ions even after forming the bond. Then why don't multiple $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ attract multiple chlorides and form something like $\ce{Mg_xCl_y}$? Why does a single molecule of the compound contain one $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ and two chlorides only?Someone said that,because more clorides would then repel one another so more clorides won't be able to stay with one  magnesium ion in one matrix .if we use the coulomb's law kq1q2÷r^2,we should find that the attraction between mg2+ and cl- would be greater than the repulsion between 2 cl-.I mean if we take q1=-1,q2=2,the force will be greater than if we take q1=q2=-1. Then the attraction force between mg ion  and cl ion should be able to surpass the repulsion between cl ions and one mg should be surrounded by more than 2 clorides in a crystal.

Comment: In solid $\ce{MgCl2}$ there are no particular molecules of $\ce{MgCl2}$. The ions are in a solid matrix.

Comment: Please guys,be sympathetic,I am just learning the ABCDs of chemistry.don't downvote it if u can't help me understand.

Comment: Alternatively, magnesium chloride can be boiled ([1412°C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_chloride)). The vapor would then likely consist of either MgCl2 molecules or a mixture of these with oligo-mers having that atomic ratio.

Comment: Thing is your premise is wrong - it happens pretty much as you think it should! Also title is wrong at the moment. It's not about proportion, but oligomerization, crystal formation and nature of ionic bond.

Comment: If you succeed in maintaining Mg2+ ions and Cl- ions in a proportion different from 2:1, the whole system will not exist more than a couple of nanoseconds. The whole system will be charged, and the excess ions will repel one another, destroying the system.

Comment: @Maurice Well, if that were to be a billion atoms with proportion 3:1 then yeah, but if proportion was, say, about 2 000 001:1 000 000 then no.

Answer (score 2):

In some sense, OP is not wrong: $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ will attract and interact with more than two $\ce{Cl-}$ (and vice versa), in that it will form an "infinite" lattice structure - an ionic crystal (and not molecules, except at extreme conditions that I will ignore here). If you consult any depiction of the structure, you see that every $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ inside the structure is surrounded (we call it coordinated) by six closest neighbours that are $\ce{Cl-}$.

However, if one were to put only ever more $\ce{Cl-}$ ions around a central $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$, the ions with the same charge would begin repelling each other. To avoid this, $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ begin grouping themselves around the charge that attracts them. In this way, the crystal forms layer by layer.

Comment: 'if one were to put only ever more Cl− ions around a central Mg2+, the ions with the same charge would begin repelling each other'.why would they repel so strongly?according to coulomb's law the attraction between mg2+ and cl- should be greater than the repulsion among cl- ions.right?the charge of mg ion is 2,whereas the charge of cl ion is 1 if we use the formula kq1q2÷r^2 , that's what we are going to find.so  Has the explanation behind that been found ,or it is what has been observed?

Comment: No. Once you have your charges balanced, you have ***two*** Cl-. They repel another Cl- with the same exact force that Mg2+ attracts it.